# How can I fix the 'Not Found' message after refreshing a subpage in my create-react-app deployed on render.com?

Tags: webpack, render.com

I am new to using render.com:

I have a create-react-app deployed as a static-site on render. All looks fine and works perfectly but when I try to refresh the browser while being at any subpage it shows a blank page with “Not Found” message on screen.

This is the only log on the production console: “GET https://www.crix.design/whatandwithwho 404”.

On Development all works perfectly and as expected.

So, my question is: Is there any setting I can modify in render.com to fix that? Or is it more likely to be a webpack issue in my project?

Thanks a lot!

My server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000 || 5001
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
// console.log('process.env.PORT----------------->', process.env.PORT)
// console.log('process.env.PORNODE_ENV----------------->', process.env.NODE_ENV)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${String(PORT)} in (${ENV}).`)
})

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server })

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('New WebSocket connection')

  // Handle incoming WebSocket messages
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(`Received message: ${message}`)

    // Process the received message or broadcast it to other connected clients
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
      if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send(message)
      }
    })
  })

  // Handle WebSocket connection close
  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed')
  })
})
```

My webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = ({ mode }) => ({
  mode,
  entry: [
    './src/index.jsx',
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  ],
  devtool: mode === 'production' ? false : 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '/public',
    hot: true,
    allowedHosts: ['all'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      favicon: './src/assets/logos/favicon.ico',
    }),
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|jpeg)$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.pdf$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.node$/,
        use: ['node-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The render.com team found the reason:

*This is a symptom of deploying your CRA to production
https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app#using-client-side-routing should get you sorted here.*